# Programmatic access to Account Teams

Tags: account-teams

Can I manage account teams via code?  I have looked for the objects that hold the data but no success.  We currently have no account teams setup, and we would like to manage them through automations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AccountTeamMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_AccountTeamMember.htm) object is what you're looking for. You can insert, update, and delete these records in Apex and the API. In Winter '20, we also have [better support](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_sales_feature_core_accounts.htm) for triggers and other internal automation (#safeharbor for now).

Comment: Thanks.  No wonder I couldn't find it.  I had to check the checkbox on Data Loader to show the secret internal objects!  Thanks for the tip.